# Override font in size class programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have font of an `testLabel` as `Helvetica Neue 12.0` in `compact width` and `compact height` class, which I set on the storyboard.

I did this in `viewWillAppear`

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)}
```

But the font did not change in the simulator. How do I override the size of font programtically?

Comment: Use the `viewDidLoad` instaed.

Comment: I did there as well, it did not work

Comment: Why? It's just work. Can you show us some codes? What did you so far?

Comment: `testLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Georgia-bold", size: 18)` Or try something like that. @Coder221

Comment: It should work irrespective whether you place it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` otherwise check your `IBOutlet` connection. Remove connection and add again.

Comment: @Coder221 Check your `@IBOutlet` connections. I think you've not connected correctly.

Comment: They are connected properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change you UILabel font in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

**Objective C:**

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    // CHANGE YOUR LABEL FONT
}
```

**Swift:**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // CHANGE YOUR LABEL FONT
    label.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)
}
```

It will work..